# JavaScript loop stops on "localStorage.removeItem"

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Why is the "localStorage.removeItem" stopping the loop? If I remove "localStorage.removeItem" and only leave the "alert", it loops though whole thing, but with "localStorage.removeItem" it stops on the first match.

```
function removeTask() {
    for (i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        checkbox = document.getElementById('utford'+i);
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            alert(i);
            localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
        }
    }
    printList();
}
```

Comment: What does your console tell you?

Comment: You should be declaring your local variables ("i", "checkbox") with `var`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy, I changed that now, but I still have same problem.

Comment: Also don't iterates forwards if you plan on deleting stuff because you modify the list as your iterating and it gets ugly.  Go with `for (var i=localStorage.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating on an array-like object while deleting its entries.
This cannot work as the entries order will be mixed up on each deletion.

Consider this example.

First iteration deletes entry #1:

```
Entry   key             value
#1      my-first-key    my-first-value
#2      my-2nd-key      my-2nd-value
```

Second iteration tries to delete entry #2:

```
Entry   key             value
#1      my-2nd-key      my-2nd-value
???     ???             ???
```

From what I make of your code, I'd advise you to use string keys instead. You could then pick the same key name as your elements' IDs.

Answer (score 6):

If you remove an item, the keys move down an index. You need to loop backwards.

```
function removeTask() {
    for (var i=localStorage.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('utford'+i);
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {            
            localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
        }
    }
    printList();
}
```